# How to upgrade the redash that running on ECS of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, upgrade, amazon-ecs, redash

Hi，I don't know how to upgrade redash ,my redash is running by ECS on AWS and it depends on redis and rds that run on AWS too.

I pulled redash from docker hub and run it by ECS on AWS,I look into this website https://redash.io/help/open-source/admin-guide/how-to-upgrade ,and get confused.Can the redash image that i pulled from docker hub can be upgraded this way just like the website says, if it can’t, so how can I upgrade it.

Comment: ya i think that it can be used to upgrade redash, why you have doubts on it ?

Comment: My doubt is the docker of redash is running on ecs,then how to change the docker-compose.yml  to it and run commands

Comment: I replied this question on our forum: https://discuss.redash.io/t/issuue-about-migrations/2968/2.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Does it finally get resolved. If yes, then how @Wloverine?

Comment: 1. Prepare two task definitions,they are the same except the redash version
2. Backup the data in postgres.
3. Stop redash server
4. ssh to ec2
5. modify the redash version of docker-compose.production.yml
6. run the command ```docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml run --rm server manage db upgrade```
7. Check the redash